# Correct way to invalidate all other http sessions for a user in Grails with Spring Security plugin on password change?

Tags: grails, spring-security, httpsession

It is best practice to invalidate any other logged-in http sessions if a user changes their password.  However, this does not happen by default in Grails with Spring Security plugin.  What is the correct code to invalidate all sessions other than the current one for a particular username?  This behaviour is observed on Grails 2.3.x and Spring Security 2.0.  If behaviour or code would be different in later versions, please include that in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think it happens automagically on any version of Grails. The way to achieve it is by using Spring SessionRegistry:

1. Configure SessionRegistry in the resources.groovy

```
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy
import org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl
import org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter

beans = {

    sessionRegistry(SessionRegistryImpl)
    concurrencyFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter){
        sessionRegistry = sessionRegistry
        expiredUrl = '/login'
    }
    sessionAuthenticationStrategy(ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy, sessionRegistry) {
        maximumSessions = -1
    }
}
```

2. Registr `concurrencyFilter` filter in the BootStrap.groovy

```
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.SecurityFilterPosition

class BootStrap {

    def init = { servletContext ->

      SpringSecurityUtils.clientRegisterFilter('concurrencyFilter', SecurityFilterPosition.CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER)

      // ...
    }
}
```

3. Add `HttpSessionEventPublisher` to the web.xml

```
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

4. Inject `sessionRegistry` into the User entity and use it to invalidate sessions when the password gets changed (in newer versions of Grails it would be rather done in a GORM event listener):

```
    def beforeUpdate() {
        if (isDirty('password')) {
            encodePassword()
            invalidateSessions()
        }
    }

    def invalidateSessions() {
        def principal =  sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals().find { it.username == username }
        if(principal) {
            sessionRegistry.getAllSessions(principal, true).each { it.expireNow() }
        }
    }
```

This solution works on Grails 2.3.11 and Spring Security 2.0.0. On newer versions things are quite different.

Comment: This is a thorough answer and I'll award bounty, thank you.   I would appreciate elaboration on the 'things that are quite different' in newer grails.  Currently on an upgrade path to grails 3 (4 doesn't look much different)

Comment: @Peter Thank you. As mentioned, the main related change in Grails is the introduction of GORM event listener. After this change, the domain objects are by default not subjects for services injection. The logic needs to be moved to a listener, e.g. autogenerated UserPasswordEncoderListener. But I think it happend in Grails  4.0.0. 
There were changes to Spring Security as well. Configuration was removed from the web.xml and listeners need to be configured programmatically e.g. using ServletListenerRegistrationBean.

Comment: @Mafor This works fine if the application is deployed on one server. What if the application is deployed on multiple servers and the user might have active sessions on these different servers. How to invalidate the user's sessions across the servers?